# Openpyxl - background color isn't saved in file

Tags: python, openpyxl

My Python script is supposed to check, whether a certain string is included in a cell. If this condition matches, the script shall change the background color of a cell in another file.
This process is repeated several times in a for-loop

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
column_color = sheet_database.cell(row = nextitem , column = 18).value
            cell_paint = sheet_blatt.cell(row = 7 + multiplicator * 10 , column = selected_column + 1).fill
            if column_color == 'AAAAAA':
                 cell_paint = PatternFill(fgColor='C00000', bgColor='C00000', fill_type='solid')

            elif column_color == 'BBBBBB':
                 cell_paint = PatternFill(fgColor='FF0000', bgColor='FF0000', fill_type='solid')
```

For some reason, the color is not saved to the file in the end.
The rest of the script just changes values of cells, so the color can not be overwritten by another part of the script.
Also, the debugger shows, that the if clause is being entered and executed.

```
wb_blatt.save('XXXX_' + str(number) + '.xlsx')
```

is used to save the final result.

Comment: I think youre supposed to use `start_color` and `end_color` when using color hex codes. see here - http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html?highlight=fgColor

Comment: Doesn't help for me. There are no changes in the files.

Comment: You could also write some conditional formatting rules to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

column_color = sheet_database.cell(row=nextitem, column=18).value
cell = sheet_blatt.cell(row=7 + multiplicator * 10, column=selected_column + 1)
if column_color == 'AAAAAA':
    cell.fill = PatternFill(fgColor='C00000', bgColor='C00000', fill_type='solid')

elif column_color == 'BBBBBB':
    cell.fill = PatternFill(fgColor='FF0000', bgColor='FF0000', fill_type='solid')
```

Comment: Thanks :) I figured it out myself a few minutes ago when I saw your post.
But why is there a difference between calling fill to a variable containing a cell object and calling fill directly to the cell object?

Comment: @Venturion As you first did it you just moved the variable reference from one `PatternFill` object to a new one, not actually changing the `fill` variable in the in the active cell (I hope it's clear enough). Maybe this is a better explenation - https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/